# Unit conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried converting this but unfortunately its not working. I am converting units such as KG, LT, Piece etc.

I do have a conversion factor.

The table that i would like to convert is as follows:

```
conversion_factor_X   Alternative_Unit  conversion_factor_Y    Unit
---------------------------------------------------------------------
          16              KG                   1               Piece
          16              LT                   1               Piece
           1              Piece                1               Piece
```

it's like 1 Piece = 16 KG, or 1 piece = 16 litres, and 1 piece = 1 piece

I tried the first part i.e. Alternative Unit and tried to convert it.. it only does for KG but not for others i.e LT and Piece.

```
select 
    --AlternativeUnit
    case 
       when stock = 0
          then 0
       else 
          case qty_unit_target 
             when 'KG'
                then 
                    case qty_unit_stock 
                       when 'KG' 
                          then qty_stock * qty_x
                       when 'ST'
                          then 
                              case qty_unit_stock 
                                 when 'ST' 
                                    then qty_stock * qty_x
                                 when 'LT'
                                    then 
                                       case qty_unit_stock 
                                          when 'LT' 
                                             then qty_stock * qty_x
                                       end  
                              end 
                    end 
          end 
    end 
from 
    xyz
```

Above it's converting for `AlternativeUnit`. At first, it checks the unit. if both are same.. it multiplies the qty with conversion rate and it checks for all the units.

Answer (score 0):

You structure seems wrong. I think should be

```
select 

--AlternativeUnit
case when stock = 0
then 0
else 
    case qty_unit_target 
      WHEN 'KG' then CASE qty_unit_stock WHEN 'KG' THEN qty_stock * qty_x END 
      WHEN 'ST' then CASE qty_unit_stock WHEN 'ST' THEN qty_stock * qty_x END
      WHEN 'LT' then CASE qty_unit_stock WHEN 'LT' THEN qty_stock * qty_x  END
    END 
END 
from xyz
```

Comment: I tried with your format.. but it only displays the values for ST and not for KG or LT.

Comment: I have looked only at the structure of your query ... check if you have proper value in  db ..